# vector field on $\mathbb{R} P^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, projective-space

Actually this is a quesion in Lee's book, Manifolds and differential geometry. I have problems working with projective spaces as manifolds.(e.g. what are curves in projective spaces ? I need to know the equivalence classes of curves to have an idea about tangent bundle... can I think of $\mathbb{R} P^2$ as the upper unit hemisphere, with half of the equator removed ? ... )  I know that the following standard charts on $\mathbb{R} P^2$ form an atlas : $$[x,y,z] \to (u_1,u_2)=(\frac{x}{z},\frac{y}{z}) \ \ \ on \ \  U_z=\{z \neq 0\}$$ $$[x,y,z] \to (v_1,v_2)=(\frac{x}{y},\frac{z}{y}) \ \ \ on \ \  U_y=\{y \neq 0\}$$ $$[x,y,z] \to (w_1,w_2)=(\frac{y}{x},\frac{z}{x}) \ \ \ on \ \  U_x=\{x \neq 0\}$$ I need to Show that there is a vector field $X$ on $\mathbb{R} P^2$ which in the last coordinate 
chart above has the following coordinate expression: $$w_1 \frac{\partial}{\partial w_1} - w_2 \frac{\partial}{\partial w_2} .$$ It is also asked that what are the coordinate expressions for the vector field $X$ in the other two charts ?

I already appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

First let us change to an easier notation.

$$V_1 :[x,y,z] \to (a_1,b_1)=(\frac{x}{z},\frac{y}{z}) \text{ on }  U_z=\{z \neq 0\}$$

$$V_2: [x,y,z] \to (a_2,b_2)=(\frac{x}{y},\frac{z}{y}) \text{ on } U_y=\{y \neq 0\}$$

$$V_3: [x,y,z] \to (a_3,b_3)=(\frac{y}{x},\frac{z}{x}) \text{ on } U_x=\{x \neq 0\}$$

You want to find a vector field $\Theta$ on $RP^2$ such that
$\Theta|_{V_3} = a_3 \frac{\partial}{\partial a_3} - b_3 \frac{\partial}{\partial b_3}$.

All we have to do is find a definition on $\Theta$ on the charts $V_1$ and $V_2$ then check that they agree on intersections.

Let us start by seeing how to define $\Theta$ on $V_2$.  We know that on $V_2 \cap V_3$, $a_3 = \frac{1}{a_2}$ and $b_3 = b_2a_3$.  By the product rule
$$0 = \Theta (a_3 a_2) = a_2\Theta(a_3) + a_3 \Theta(a_2)$$
so we know that $$\Theta(a_2) = -a_2$$
Likewise we can compute
$$\Theta(b_2) = -2b_2$$
Therefore we can conjecture if such a $\Theta$ exists then
$$\Theta|_{V_2} = -a_2\frac{\partial}{\partial a_2} - 2b_2 \frac{\partial}{\partial b_2}$$

Now do the same type of computation for $V_1$ and check that they agree on intersections.

If you've learned about homogenous coordinates these computations tend to be easier to do using that language.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I have some questions about your answer. 1) In the 4-5 th line , you mean "on $V_2 \cap V_3$" ? 2) I see why $a_3=\frac{1}{a_2}$, but I don't understand why $b_3=\frac{1}{b_2}$ ? I computed and got $b_3=a_3 b_2$ ... 3) $\Theta$ is a vector field , i.e. is a map $\Theta : \mathbb{R}P^2 \to T\mathbb{R}P^2$, therefore $\Theta (a_3)$ does not make sense to me, since $a_3 \notin \mathbb{R}P^2$ but $a_3 \in \mathbb{R}^2$, I would be thankful if you can clarify these...

Comment: Thanks. You commented as I was making edits.  Hopefully it is right now.

Comment: By $\Theta(a_3)$ I mean the vector field $\Theta$ acting on the coordinate function of $a_3$. My mistake I should have been more clear.